# What is the chance that this code terminates?

Tags: trees, probability-theory, termination

I wrote this Python code, and wondered if it sometimes *simply doesn't* terminate (assuming we had infinite memory/time and no recursion depth limit).

Intuitively you'd think it terminates, since at some point you must get *lucky*, and if it doesn't terminate you have an infinite amount of time to get lucky. On the other hand, as the recursion depth increases you must become exponentially more lucky.

```
import random

def random_tree():
    if random.random() < 0.5:
        return 0
    return [random_tree() for _ in range(random.randint(1, 5))]
```

If `random_tree` doesn't always terminate, why, and what is the chance that it does terminate?

I've tried to calculate it using $P = 1 - (1 - 0.5)(1 - (P + P^2 + P^3 + P^4 + P^5)/5)$, which in it's terrific uselessness either gives the answer ~$0.684124$ or... $1$.

Probably more complicated, but also intriguing to me, what is the termination chance  $P(a, b)$ for:

```
def random_tree(a, b):
    if random.random() < a:
        return 0
    return [random_tree(a, b) for _ in range(random.randint(1, b))]
```

Or in pseudo-code:

```
random_tree(a, b) is a function that either:
    - returns 0 with probability a
    - returns a list containing the results of 1 to b
      (uniformly chosen from this inclusive range) recursive calls

random_tree(a, b):
    if rand() < a # rand() is a random real on [0, 1)
        return 0
    list = []
    len = randint(1, b) # uniform random integer from 1 to b inclusive
    do len times
        append random_tree(a, b) to list
    return list
```

Comment: @DavidRicherby Added in the bottom. The code at the top is simply `random_tree(0.5, 5)`.

Comment: This is known as a branching process. Look it up to find the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an example of a [branching process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_process). The behavior of a branching process depends on the expected number of children, which in your case is $1.25 > 1$. When this number is at most 1, the process gets extinct with probability 1. When the number is more than 1, it has a chance of surviving forever; the extinction probability is just what you calculated — you need to select the root which is smaller than 1.

Comment: Why is the root of $1$ invalid?

Comment: So it turns out. This root expresses the fact that if you never start then the process gets extinct. I suggest you do some reading on this classical topic, which is treated for example by Feller.